# AWK and matrices handling

Tags: matrix, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to handle (in awk) a square and symmetric matrix to do:

1. Identify the row with only zeros.
2. Delete that row and its symmetric column.
3. Print the resultant matrix.

**Input**

```
  1234567
 xabcdefg
1a0101101
2b1010001
3c0101001
4d1010101
5e1001000
6f0000000
7g1111000
```

**Expected output** *Sixth row and column deleted*

```
  123457
 xabcdeg
1a010111
2b101001
3c010101
4d101011
5e100100
7g111100
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: are the 1234..7 and abcdefg.. in input  file?

Comment: nope, it's just to identify each row and column, as you prefer, with letters or numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line should work:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==FNR{if(/^0+$/)z[NR];next}
                      !(FNR in z){for(x in z)$x="";print}' file file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
0101101
1010001
0101001
1010101
1001000
0000000
1111000

kent$  awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==FNR{if(/^0+$/)z[NR];next}!(FNR in z){for(x in z)$x="";print}' f f 
010111
101001
010101
101011
100100
111100
```

it works for multiple "all-zero" rows too:

```
kent$  cat f
00001
00000
00000
00000
10000

kent$  awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==FNR{if(/^0+$/)z[NR];next}!(FNR in z){for(x in z)$x="";print}' f f
01
10
```

Comment: Thank so much, it works smoothly. :D Kent, would it be too much if I ask you how it works? (I just want to learn). Thank in advance. ( :

Comment: @Alejandro I read the input file twice, first time is to locate the all zero rows index (row number), 2nd time, print the matrix, skip the located row numbers also the column numbers.

Comment: By the way @Kent, hope this is not too late to ask you: how can the code show, also, the NR deleted? Thank in advance

Comment: @Alejandro the all zero rows' indexes are stored in `z` array. do a `for(x in z)print x` you see all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{row[NR]=$0} $0=='0000000' {bad=NR} END{for (i=1;i<=NR;i=i+1+(i==bad-1)) {print substr(row[i],1,bad-1) substr(row[i],bad+1)}}' input
010111
101001
010101
101011
100100
111100
```

Comment: Thank John1024. But, I prefer Kent's one, it is more general. Have a good day ( :